# Passing CiviCRM invoice number to Moneris hosted payment page

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

We use this extension to hook CiviCRM up to Moneris' hosted payment page to process payments: https://github.com/webaccess/com.webaccessglobal.moneriseselect

Could someone help point me in the right direction as to how to pass along the Invoice # to Moneris so that reconciliation between Moneris transactions and CiviCRM contributions can be more straight forward?

Or share some tips on best practices for this kind of reconciliation?

Comment: 'order_id' => $params['invoiceID'], - Invoice number is already sent to the payment processor - is this not recorded against the server or do you want to do something else ..

Comment: Hi Ramesh - thanks. I'm going to check with the client. Essentially, they're saying that when they pull a transaction report out of Moneris, there's no invoice # on the Moneris end to reconcile with the invoice #s in CiviCRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - we figured out the issue - the client just didn't have his export settings in Moneris correct. He was only querying a couple fields.

Thank you for your help Ramesh!

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case - Looking at the code I can see that in the confirmation page you are redirecting to Moneries Site for entering Card details and then once the payment is processed "Successfull/Failed" it is redirected again to CiviCRM Page.

So at that time please read the order number from the payment details and update that against your contribution - which will be usefully for your client to link both the records - I guess this helps